# Part file not getting saved to the database

Tags: hibernate, blob

```
public String addFile(UploadFileBean uploadFileBean) throws Exception {
SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtility.createSessionFactory();
    Session session = null;
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    UploadFileEntity uploadFileEntity = new UploadFileEntity();

    InputStream input = uploadFileBean.getFileData().getInputStream();
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];
    for (int length = 0; (length = input.read(buffer)) > 0;)
        output.write(buffer, 0, length);

    uploadFileEntity.setUploaderId(uploadFileBean.getUploaderId());
    uploadFileEntity.setReviewerId(uploadFileBean.getReviewerId());
    uploadFileEntity.setFileData(output.toByteArray());
    uploadFileEntity.setFileName(uploadFileBean.getFileName());
    uploadFileEntity.setFileStatus("Pending");

    session.persist(uploadFileEntity);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();

    return null;
}
```

This is the code that I am using to convert the part file to bytes and saving it to the database in BLOB format. But once the code executes completely, nothing is getting saved to the database and it shows null. Can someone please suggest what could be the possible fault?

[Image of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwaqB.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your output is not closed.The data was still in the cache which needs flushed.

Comment: How to do it?
BTW the rest of the data is getting saved to database except the file

Comment: just add `output.close();` after `uploadFileEntity.setFileStatus("Pending");`

Comment: try to add `output.flush();` after `uploadFileEntity.setReviewerId(uploadFileBean.getReviewerId());`, if it still does not work, i do not know why^()^